# Изменение нижней части экрана в iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, scrollview

Делаю простой калькулятор, экран делится на две части: сверху - табло с результатом, снизу - клавиатура (создаю ее сам из кнопок разных). Планирую прикрутить свайп (движение пальцем влево/вправо), при таком движении перемещается не экран целиком, а клавиатура меняется с обычными действиями (умножение, деление) на клавиатуру с расширенными операциями. Вот как сделать подобную UIView чтобы при свайпе менялась только нижняя часть экрана? Это ведь явно несколько UIView создавать, а как их тогда склеивать?

**UPDATE**:

Вроде разобрался, не знаю насколько правильно, но вот код, может кому пригодится:

```
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.pagingEnabled = true

redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(redView)

greenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(greenView)


let views = [
    "greenView"  : greenView,
    "redView"    : redView,
    "view"       : containerView
]


view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[redView(==view)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[greenView(==view)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[redView(==view)][greenView(==view)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

Где containerView - UIScrollView

redView и greenView - UIView

Comment: Вам надо к своему `self.view` у контроллера прикрутить два сабвью каждый размером с пол экрана: верхний - калькулятор, и нижний - `UIScrollView` с pagingEnabled. Этому вью сделать размер шириной в два экрана, на первом одна клава, на втором другая. Все.

Answer (score 1):

На нижнюю половину экрана добавляй сразу обе клавиатуры. Простую ставишь на экран (x=0). Расширенную ставишь слева (за пределами экрана): x = -vc.view.frame.size.width

При свайпе (UISwipeGestureRecognizer) слева на право у расширенной клавиатуры ставишь x = 0, у простой - x = vc.view.frame.size.width.
Меняешь в блоке [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.3 animations:^{}];

Ширина клавиатур всегда = vc.view.frame.size.width.